# Como pegar o retorno de um HTTP POST (IOS SWIFT)

Tags: http, post

Eu preciso fazer um HTTP POST para uma pagina que simplesmente retorna uma literal (que pode ser "OK" ou "ERRO") Eu pequei um [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTj0ZLha1zE) da WEB que mostra como fazer isso e ele retorno um JSON, segui o tutorial e ele funciona perfeitamente.

Meu problema está exatamente ai... ele retorna um JSON e o que meu site retorna não é um JSON e sim um simples literal..

Como faço para pegar essa literal que o site está retornando... já tentei várias alterações no código abaixo mas sem sucesso.

```
let parameters = ["username": "@kilo_loco", "tweet": "HelloWorld"]

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/ola.php") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    //request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print ("*******")
            print(response)
        }

        //print(data as Any)

        if let data = data {
            print("** TESTE **")
           print(data)
            //do {
              //  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                //print(json)
            //} catch {
              //  print(error)
           // }
        }

    }.resume()
```

O Último "Print(data) me retorna o tamanho em bytes e não o conteúdo da literal..

Answer (score -1):

Você te que formatar os dados de retorno da api como JSON

Exemplo:

```
$return = array(
    'sucesso' => 1,
    'usuario' => $usuario
    );

echo json_encode($return);
```